# Text Summerization task NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I'm working on a text summarization task, I have fine-tuned Google's Pegasus model for my specific use case, here is the problem I am facing and I would like some expert opinions on which direction to move forward.

I have a dataset of 300 news articles each around 500-700 words with a summary of around 100-130 words. The fine-tuned model is doing pretty well in producing summaries of the same length, but I want to generate a 30-50 word summary. Now when I limit the output size to 50 words the model is not able to complete the whole summary. I am aware that it is the problem with the dataset i.e to generate a 30-50 word summary I should fine-tune the model with the same length dataset. Generating a new dataset is painful as we all are aware.

If anyone can suggest a solution or any possible direction to solve this problem without changing the dataset, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in assuming that the model is unable to complete 30-50 word summaries due to the fact that it was trained on target summaries of 100-130 words. Unfortunately I don't think there's anything you can do other than create a new dataset for your use case.

You could either find a different existing dataset with shorter target summaries or make the summaries yourself. You can either make the summaries yourself by manually annotating samples from scratch or using tools like [Quillbot](https://quillbot.com/) or PoS tagging to give yourself "hints" when conducting annotation.